# Check if multiple files exist in directory

Tags: shell, files, wildcards

How to find multiple files present in a directory in `ksh` (on `AIX`)

I am trying below one:

```
if [ $# -lt 1 ];then
    echo "Please enter the path"
    exit
fi
path=$1
if [ [ ! f $path/cc*.csv ] && [ ! f $path/cc*.rpt ] && [ ! f $path/*.xls ] ];then
    echo "All required files are not present\n"
fi
```

I am getting error like `check[6]: !: unknown test operator` //check is my file name.

what is wrong in my script. Could someone help me on this.

Comment: If they are _required_, then it seems to me your script should fail if _any_ of them is missing, not if _all_ of them are missing.

Answer (score 4):

`test -f` won't work for multiple files expanded from wildcards.  Instead you might well use a shell function with null-redirected `ls`.

```
present() {
        ls "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1
}

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Please enter the path"
    exit
fi
path=$1
if ! present $path/cc*.csv && ! present $path/cc*.rpt && ! present $path/*.xls; then
    echo "All required files are not present\n"
fi
```

Btw is it fine to use `&&`?  In this case you get `not present` only when there're no files named `cc*.csv` or `cc*.rpt` or `cc*.xls` in `$path`.

Comment: difference to `test -f`: `ls` will not report a failure when the files is a broken symlink (pointing to nowhere), or when the "file" is a directory.

Answer (score 3):

```
if [ [ ! f $path/cc*.csv ] && [ ! f $path/cc*.rpt ] && [ ! f $path/*.xls ] ];then
    echo "All required files are not present\n" fi
```

`check[6]: !`: unknown test operator

I think you forgot the operand '`f`' is an unkown operand --> '**`-f`**'

```
if [ [ ! -f $path/cc*.csv ] && [ ! -f $path/cc*.rpt ] && [ ! -f $path/*.xls ] ];then
    echo "All required files are not present\n"
fi
```

In your case you *all* files have to be missing before it will echo your ... it of course depend on your goal.

I'm not able to check it out in ksh on AIX.